# how can i stop my sound file from being auto download in php jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have following code in my php jquery call...

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mysounds/player.swf" id="audioplayer1" height="1" width="1"> 
<param name="movie" value="mysounds/player.swf" /> 
<param name="FlashVars" value="playerID=audioplayer1&autostart=yes&soundFile=mysounds/online.mp3" /> 
<param name="quality" value="high" /> 
<param name="menu" value="false" /> 
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" /> 
</object>
```

and i have internetdownloadmanager installed on my pc

when ever i try to load the page it start downloading the sound with internetdownloadmanager how can i stop that....and prevent it from auto downloading from any downloader...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows you might want to change the file associations for mp3 files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your download manager program scans the whole file for URLs that may lead to an MP3 file, and tries to download them.

While this is a very localized problem - not everyone has such a download manager installed - you might be able to circumvent this by simply giving the MP3 file a different file extension - or none at all:

```
soundFile=mysounds/online
```

whether your Flash player will accept the missing or incorrect file extension you'd have to try out, but I think it will.

The basic fact that your sound file can be downloaded when you use it in a Flash player this way remains.

Comment: but it is doing the same job and starting the file auto on page load

Comment: @testkham wait, what exactly is your problem. That the file starts downloading in your downloader, or that it starts *playing?*

Comment: it starts downloading while i only want it to play

Comment: @testkhan so it starts downloading even if you change the file name and remove the `.mp3`?